# NumberFormatException when reading from System.in

Tags: java, system.in

I am getting these exception while running the code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Ideone.main(Main.java:22)
```

I am new at java and unable to resolve this error. Please help !
Here  is my code ->

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class etest {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception{
        int n,k;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = in.nextInt();
        k = in.nextInt();
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        //StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(input.readLine());
        int total=0;
        int values[] = new int[n];
        for(int i =0; i<n; i++) {
            values[i] = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
            if ((values[i]%k)==0) {
                total++ ;
            }
            input.close();
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

I am using the following input sample to run the program.
Thank you so much for any help!

```
7 3
1
51
966369
7
9
999996
11
```

Comment: If your stream is exhausted, `input.readLine()` returns `null`

Comment: So how to overcome this?

Comment: Wouldnt this be much easier with just the `Scanner` and having something like `while (scanner.hasNextInt()) { values[i] = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextInt()); }`

Comment: @Jyr there is no need to do `Integer.parseInt` for `scanner.nextInt()` because already that is `int`

Comment: You are trying too many things at a time ...use either `Scanner` or `BuffredReader` keep it simple ,close the IO stream immediately after use (if it has no further use)

Comment: @Prashant True. It was a fast comment and I wasn't paying enough attention obviously ;).

Comment: What exactly is this code supposed to do?

Comment: @deme72 The input begins with two positive integers n k (n, k<=10^7). The next n lines of input contain one positive integer ti, not greater than 10^9, each and output denoting how many integers ti are divisible by k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your program has too many errors :

You can change your code as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    int n, k;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = in.nextInt();
    k = in.nextInt();
    int total = 0;
    int values[] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        values[i] = in.nextInt();
        if ((values[i] % k) == 0) {
            total++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

1) you should not close BufferedReader it will automatically close input stream also.

2) you don't need Scanner and BufferedReader at the same time. your solution can use any one of them.

3) better to use try-catch while using `Integer.parseInt(String str);`

if you want to go with BufferedReader then you need to change your code as

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    int n, k;


    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str[]= input.readLine().split(" ");
    n = Integer.parseInt(str[0]);
    k = Integer.parseInt(str[1]);
    int total = 0;
    int values[] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        values[i]=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        if ((values[i] % k) == 0) {
            total++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

Comment: This will take too much time and I have to use Buffered Reader to solve this in less time

Comment: @AkashKesarwani why do you have a time restraint

Comment: @deme72 I have a time restraint  at least 2.5MB of input data per second at runtime

Comment: @AkashKesarwani : i changed scanner with BufferedReader.

Comment: @Prashant now this is working. I think it is because of using two different methods in the same program. Thanks for help